# Vlookups/Index Match not working with wildcards(*) and large list of URLs

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to to a VLOOKUP based on a partial text match.  I can get it working with simple dummy data, but once I put it into my actual worksheet it doesn't seem to work as expected.

A1: `www1.macys.com/cms/slp/2/1-Carat-Diamond-Earrings`

B1: `www1.macys.com/shop/jewelry-watches/fine-jewelry/Jewelry_type,Sortby,Productsperpage/Earrings,ORIGINAL,40?id=21996,www1.macys.com/shop/jewelry-watches/fine-jewelry/Jewelry_type,Sortby,Productsperpage/Necklaces,ORIGINAL,40?id=21996,www1.macys.com/shop/jewelry-watches/fine-jewelry/Jewelry_type,Sortby,Productsperpage/Bracelets,ORIGINAL,40?id=21996,www1.macys.com/shop/jewelry-watches/fine-jewelry/Jewelry_type,Sortby,Productsperpage/Rings,ORIGINAL,40?id=21996,`

C1: `www1.macys.com/shop/jewelry-watches/fine-jewelry/Jewelry_type,Sortby,Productsperpage/Bracelets,ORIGINAL,40?id=21996`

I need to look at column C, match it with one of the values in column B, then return column A.  Pretend that Column B has multiple cells with that same format (lots of URLs that are concatenated with a comma).  I've tried VLOOKUPs with a wildcard, but that still doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas on why this isn't working?

Comment: What error do you get? Vlookup can only return values to the right of the lookup column. If your A1, B1, C1 are in that order and you want to lookup a value in C1 to return the value in A1, Vlookup won't work. But first: what error? Post a screenshot of your data. Think file sharing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think "the penny has dropped" - B1 has exceeded a limit (255 characters). You may need to split it into several cells (probably repeating 'A1' values next to each) while ensuring the parsing does not break a C1 match into two (so perhaps at the commas).